# Spring: Map a JSON to String when JSON keys are unknown

Tags: spring, api, fasterxml

Is it possible to map a JSON to a String if its keys are unknown ? Here is a JSON I get for API:

```
{
  "key1.abc": "Some translation",
  "key2.abc": "Some other translation",
...
}
```

I tried as follows:

```
ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, String.class);
```

but it failed with error:

```
JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token
```

Any ideas ? Thank you

Comment: Why do you need it to be a String?

Answer (score 2):

Finally, the solution I came to is the following. When I get a response in this form:

```
{
  "some.translation.key": "traslated text",
  "other.translation.key": "other traslated text"
}
```

Jackson parser never considers it to be a String but an Object to map to. That's why I had to map the response to a Map.
To achieve this, I had to define `ParameterizedTypeReference`of Map type:

```
ParameterizedTypeReference<Map<String, String>> typeRef = new ParameterizedTypeReference<Map<String, String>>() {};
```

Then pass it in to the `exchange` method:

```
restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, typeRef);
```

where entity is an instance of `HttpEntity<Object>` class.

Having all the translations saved in the Map, it is easy to get a translation knowing the corresponding key:

```
map.get("some.translation.key");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject json= searchResult.getJSONObject("json");
Iterator keys = json.keys();

while(keys.hasNext()) {
    // loop to get the dynamic key
    String currentDynamicKey = (String)keys.next();

    // get the value of the dynamic key
    JSONObject currentDynamicValue = questionMark.getJSONObject(currentDynamicKey);

    // do something here with the value...
}
```

Comment: The question is not about to find a key in the supplied JSON but about how to fix it when using with Spring `RestTemplate#exchange` method. It tries to deserialize it to a Java object.